# C# IRC & Twitch Idle Disconnection?

Tags: c#, irc, twitch

I am trying to make a twitch chat logger, however the bot works for X amount of minutes and then disconnects. I read that its because the bot is inactive, and I read that I need to send a ping but I'm not 100% sure how to fully do it. Any help would be great :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

IRC has a keep alive system that detects dead clients.

You should probably start by reading the [IRC Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2812), particularly, the [PNG PONG](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2812#section-3.7.2) section.

Every X time, a PING message is sent from the server, usually with a payload, your client needs to make a response with a PONG message (and the payload) before the next PING message gets sent. If a second PING message is sent before a PONG response is sent, the server will forcibly disconnect your client.

Comment: So I think this has worked, I'm getting a null error now but I think its the way I'm handling messages. Thanks :)